# Redirect masked URL to different domain on same server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, html, multiple-domains

I'm trying to use an existing server to essentially run 2 websites. At present there are 2 domains pointing to the same location:

- `schoc.co.nz` - the main website,
- `chocolatetherapy.com` - the desired additional website.

The Schoc site runs just fine, the other site is the challenge. So it seems possible to have files and subfolders that can be addressed like this:

`http://www.chocolatetherapy.com/homepage.htm`

And,

`http://www.chocolatetherapy.com/contact/`

So ideally I want to have 2 homepages on the same server, one that appears with schoc.co.nz, the other (above) with chocolatetherapy.com - can I use an htaccess file?

I know the logical thing to do would be these on separate servers, but the domains and hosting is fairly entangled and I'm afraid to start making changes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest was to be able to do this if you can forward the domain, but mask it with your meta tags, for example if you are with Godaddy, there is a option to forward with masking, you would then set up another directory within your server for example

```
Public_html/chocolatetherapy
```

and you will have your original `schoc.co.nz` website in the public html directory.

You would then forward the domain of chocolatetherapy.com to

```
schoc.co.nz/chocolatetherapy/index.html
```

but mask it so it only shows chocolatetherapy.com

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That sounds sensible although the Schoc.co.nz site actually runs on a server set up as chocolatetherapy.com rather than the other way around - if you see what I mean. And I don't want to make changes that might impact the schoc.co.nz domain (such as moving the whole site to Public_html/schoc.

Comment: Thats no problem then point the domain chocolatetherapy.com to chocolatetherapy.com/schoc/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look once I can get logged into the cpanel